# SQL: Having trouble with needing dynamic logic in a scalar User Defined Function

Tags: sql, database, mysql-workbench

For an assignment, I have to fill in the body of a User Defined Scalar function to calculate a simple linear regression model without the intercept term as a result. The input is two lists of comma-separated floats (input as one string each). I have to somehow split the strings along the commas into separate float values for the X and Ys, then do the proper calculations on them to achieve the return slope variable.

I'm as far as splitting the string to get the first float value, however, I'm running into issues performing dynamic calculations such as using a while loop to determine all the values from the string.

Is there any way around this for a UDF? Most of the function was given already and we have to make it work with our answer- we can't change a lot of it such as the UDF being scalar and the input and return parameters.

I've been scratching my head over this for hours and I'm happy for even the progress that I've made, I can't find any similar searches on it. Thanks for any help in advance!

```
/*-- =============================================
-- Description: Calculates Simple Linear Regression Model Without The Intercept Term
-- Resources: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression
-- Requirements of Task: Create a Scalar User Defined Function That Inputs Two -- -- Variable Comma
Separated Float String Lists And Calculates Simple Linear Regression Model Without The Intercept Term
as The Result.
*/
/*
SELECT cudf('1,2,3','1,2,3') AS SLOPE -- Result = 1
SELECT cudf('1,2,3','3,2,1')
AS SLOPE -- Result = -1
SELECT cudf
('1.47,1.50,1.52,1.55,1.57,1.60,1.63,1.65,1.68,1.70,1.73,1.75,1.78,1.80,1.83',
'52.21,53.12,54.48,55.84,57.20,58.57,59.93,61.29,63.11,64.47,66.28,68.10,69.92,72.19,74.46')
AS SLOPE -- Result = 61.2721865421079
*/
-- =============================================
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `cudf`;
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION `cudf`
(

    cXPoints VARCHAR(255)
    ,cYPoints VARCHAR(255)

)
RETURNS FLOAT
BEGIN

-- Declare the return variable here
DECLARE Result DECIMAL(10, 4);

DECLARE beginV INT;
DECLARE countV INT;
DECLARE maxV INT;
DECLARE xVal FLOAT;
DECLARE xSum FLOAT;
DECLARE a INT(2); 
SET Result = NULL;
SET xSum = 0;
/* Your Magic / Answer / Solution Goes HERE :) */
WHILE length(cXPoints) > 0 AS LOOP
    BEGIN
        SET beginV= locate(',', cXPoints);
        SET xVal = CASE WHEN beginV = 0 THEn cXPoints ELSE SUBSTRING(cXPoints, 1, beginV - 1) END;
        SET xSum = xSum + xVal;
        #INSERT INTO TempTable2 Values(xVal);
        SET cXPoints = CASE WHEN beginV = 0 THEn cXPoints = '' ELSE SUBSTRING(cXPoints, beginV + 1, length(cXPoints) - beginV) END;
    END;
END; 

-- Return the result of the function
RETURN xSum;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Here is what I have so far... the lines Ive added are some of the variables and the while loop. The while loop doesnt function. If i comment out the while loop, the inner code works just on the first variable of the X list.

The mathematical logic (I think) is to return the sum of each x * y variable divided by the sum of each x variable squared.